# _getexif not working when applied to an image

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am using _getexif() method on an image, but I am getting this error:

```
in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: _getexif
```

This is the function I am using for getting it:

```
def get_exif():
    global image_object
    exif_data = image_object._getexif()
    for tag_id in exif_data:
        tag_name = TAGS.get(tag_id, tag_id)
        value = exif_data.get(tag_id)
        print(f"{tag_name:25}: {value}")
```

and this is the image I'm applying it on:

```
def browse_image():
    global image_object, image_loaded_label
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select An Image",
                                               filetypes=(("jpeg files", "*.jpeg"), ("png files", "*.png")))
    image = Image.open(root.filename)
    image_object = image.resize((450, 350), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image_loaded = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_object)
    img_lbl.configure(image=image_loaded)
    img_lbl.image = image_loaded
    exif_lbl.configure(text="")
```

The weird thing is when I use these 3 lines

```
image_loaded_label = Label(image=image_loaded)
    image_loaded_label.pack()
    image_loaded_label.image = image_loaded
```

instead of doing this:

```
img_lbl.configure(image=image_loaded)
 img_lbl.image = image_loaded

img_lbl = Label(root)
img_lbl.pack()
```

it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try `get_exif()` instead (without the underscore). ([source](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getexif)). I think `_get_exif()` was for PIL, not the new version Pillow.

Comment: Thanks, getexif() without underscore works fine with my new code. It's weird that _getxeif() works with the other piece of code instead

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why it does that.